# Linear approximation in three dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be defined by $$f(x,y,z)=(\cos z,e^{2x}+\sin y)$$ Find the linearization of $f(x,y,z)$ at the point $(0,0,0)$.

I'm having trouble starting this problem mostly because all of the examples I've seen are in the form (example) $z=x+y$ where there's no comma listed in the function.

Comment: linearize each one of them separately

Comment: Thank you. I've linearized them both separately. Do I keep them separate or add them together?

Comment: It is a vector form of two functions, your answwer should be in the same form (separate by comma).

Comment: Okay awesome. Thank you!